# passwordless ssh for another username?

Tags: ssh, password, subversion

I want to do a passwordless ssh connection for a subversion project. Right now I'm using ssh+svn, and it's a little annoying, because I have to type the password any time I want to transact with the server.

I've found several tutorials on the web about how to generate a key for passwordless ssh, but they all seem to assume that I'm using the same username on the remote system as I am for my home system. However, the username that I use for ssh+svn is different that the user account name on the system that I'm running. How do I set this up properly? I haven't had luck with just changing the name in the key file.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You just have to supply the other system's username in the `svn` command:

```
$ svn co svn+ssh://otheruser@othersystem/path/to/repo
```

To answer your question's title, too:

```
$ ssh otheruser@othersystem
```

This causes `sshd` on the remote machine to look in `~otheruser/.ssh/authorized_keys` for the public key corresponding to the private key on the machine you're typing the command on.

Comment: So part of the instructions were to make a file `.ssh/id_rsa.pub`, and upload it to the remote server. When I made it, it ended with localusername@localsystem. That should be changed to remoteusername@remotesystem, right? Both locally and remotely?

Comment: No.  Just append the contents of your local `id_rsa.pub` to `authorized_keys` on the remote system.  It'll work.

Comment: alternately, many systems have ssh-copy-id to solve this problem: "ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub username@remote-machine"

Comment: Unfortunately, many do not, and it seems this is not a standard part of OpenSSH, so there are at least a couple of different implementations of this script floating around.

Comment: If you are using gnome seahorse have automated deployment of keys.

Answer (score 9):

There are two ways to do this:

1) put user@ into the svn url ; this tells svn+ssh to login as that user.  I think it's kind of a bad idea from a maintenance perspective because things like externals that point at other parts of the repository won't work correctly.

2) make a ~/.ssh/config (documented as [ssh_config](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config)) that says something like:

```
Host othersystem
  User otheruser
```

this way *any* attempt to ssh to othersystem will default to using otheruser.  Which is handy for you when do ssh manually as well as when you're using svn.

Answer (score 8):

You don't have to have the same username on both machines. As long as you generate the key (`ssh-keygen`), you have to copy line from `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` or `~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub` (depending on type of key) from local server and append it to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on remote.

```
% ssh-keygen
% cat ~/.ssh/id_*.pub | ssh remoteuser@remoteserver 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
```

If you don't want to type `remoteuser` each time, append to `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host remoteserver
    User remoteuser
```

P.S. The *name* of key may be in form of `localuser@localhost` but it is **only a name**. It can be just as well `myfavouritekey@myfavouritecomputer` and no one would care.

Comment: The "cat" command above is the core of the common but nonstandard `ssh-copy-id` script mentioned above.  I recognize it because not all the systems I use come with `ssh-copy-id`, so I've typed something like that more than a few times. :)

Comment: I've never heard about `ssh-copy-id`. I usually use `vim` or `seahorse` ;)

Answer (score 0):

After I create `.ssh/config` and run:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_*.pub | ssh remoteuser@remoteserver 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
```

I get the error:

```
Bad owner or permissions on /usr/share/eprints3/.ssh/config
```

Then I added `chmod 600 .ssh/config`, and after that, it is running smoothly.